# How to get list of user in Active Directory without memory leak using C#

Tags: c#, memory-leaks, active-directory

I have more than 8,00,000 records in Active Directory. I have to fetch all the users from AD. But I'm facing Memory Leak issue.

Anyhow I ran in the server. It reached around 10 GB RAM size to complete the task successfully.

Instead of fetching all the 8,00,000 records at a time, I am planning to get the records in groups. All the users are grouped by department wise. Hence, I want to use this department field to fetch the records group wise. Can anyone please suggest me how this can be achieved without any memory leak issue?

Here is my query to fetch all the users by department wise. But I couldn't find the best way to fetch the Unique department from AD. which would take less time to get execute.

```
    public void GetUserFromGroup(String Department)
    {
        try
        {
            DirectoryEntry entry = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://" + domainName, userName, passwd, AuthenticationTypes.Secure);
            DirectorySearcher dSearch = new DirectorySearcher(entry);
            dSearch.PageSize = 1000;
            dSearch.Filter = "(&(objectClass=*)(displayname=*)(Department=" + Department + "))";
            dSearch.SearchScope = SearchScope.Subtree;
            SearchResultCollection src = dSearch.FindAll();

            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.Add("displayname");

            foreach (SearchResult sResultSet in src)
            {
                DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();

                if (GetProperty(sResultSet, "displayname") != "")
                {
                    dr["displayname"] = GetProperty(sResultSet, "displayname").ToString();
                }
                else
                {
                    dr["displayname"] = null;
                }

                dt.Rows.Add(dr);
            }
            src.Dispose();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }

        public static string GetProperty(SearchResult searchResult, string PropertyName)
        {
            try
            {
                if (searchResult.Properties.Contains(PropertyName))
                {
                        return searchResult.Properties[PropertyName][0].ToString();
                }
                else
                {
                        return string.Empty;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
        }
```

Comment: It will take log time to do this task....instead of that pls check if there is a text file named as "Associate.txt" where all the active directory users are available. if so, then create a stored procedure to retrieve the data from that text file and store in a table.Then, from you ur apps you can connect to the newly created table

Comment: Thanks for your comments. But where can I find the "Associate.txt" File?

Comment: check with your team lead/manager. for all companies where they access active directory, used to keep it

Comment: I have CSV of the data and bulk insert into the database. However fields like displayname will have a comma as part of the name. How do I over come this issue to seprate the values for each field and insert the correct data in to the database.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could try to just load the needed properties:

```
dsearch.PropertiesToLoad.Add("displayname");
```